# Splitting values in a list and making variables of them

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list which looks like this:

`list1 = ['a', '1-1-2020', '100', 'a->:100, b->:100, c->:50, d->:90']`

I would like to make 4 variables of `a->:100 // b->:100 // c->:50 // d->:90`. Something like this:

`var1 would be = a->:100` and
`var2 would be = b->:100`
etc.

my code right now is:

```
for i in list1:
   z = [x.split(',')[3] for x in list1)
   var1 = z[0]
   var2 = z[1]
   var3 = z[2]
   var4 = z[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead make a dictionary of key value pairs

```
In [7]: list1
Out[7]: ['a', '1-1-2020', '100', 'a->:100, b->:100, c->:50, d->:90']

In [8]: {i.split("->:")[0].strip():i.split("->:")[1].strip() for i in list1[-1].split(",")}
Out[8]: {'a': '100', 'b': '100', 'c': '50', 'd': '90'}
```

Update:
If you want to use variables only then

```
In [21]: list1 = ['a', '1-1-2020', '100', 'a->:100, b->:100, c->:50, d->:90']
In [23]: list1_split = list1[-1].split(",")
In [32]: var1 = list1_split[0].strip()

In [33]: var2 = list1_split[1].strip()

In [34]: var3 = list1_split[2].strip()

In [35]: var4 = list1_split[3].strip()

In [36]: var1
Out[36]: 'a->:100'

In [37]: var2
Out[37]: 'b->:100'

In [38]: var3
Out[38]: 'c->:50'

In [39]: var4
Out[39]: 'd->:90'
```

Comment: How do you make a dictionary out of list1? please note iam using Spyder.

Comment: According to your output, you need to split the last element of the list, right? Copy the 2nd statement and run it in spyderr

Comment: aha True it works What if I want the '->:' in my output also?

Comment: Can you give an example? @Premier12

Comment: I want this as a variable `var1 = 'a->:100'`

Comment: Instead of var1, you can access the same value using dictionary get

Comment: what If I want to compare if var 1 is bigger then var 2 for example?

Comment: You can do `if int(var1[var1.index(":")+1:]) > int(var2[var2.index(":")+1:]):`. This will consider everything to the left of the colon part of the number to be compared.